# Pdf uploading without using input box in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a javascript code to annotate the pdf within the browser and after annnotating i am saving it to mydevice and then uploading it using another form.

but i want it be uploaded into the local storage of web page and then upload automatically to my upload.php

```
function printPDF() {
    const printWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    const printDoc = printWindow.document;

    for (let i = 0; i <= pdfDoc.numPages; i++) {
        pdfDoc.getPage(i).then(page => {
            const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            canvas.height = viewport.height;

            const renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            };

            page.render(renderContext).promise.then(() => {
                renderAnnotationsOnCanvas(context, i); // Render annotations on the canvas
                const imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
                printDoc.write('<img src="' + imageData + '" style="max-width: 100%;">');
                if (i === pdfDoc.numPages) {
                    printDoc.close();
                    printWindow.onload = function () {
                        printWindow.print();
                        printWindow.close();
                    };
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

this is output window we get after the print pdf get trigger this just an example:

[image: this is output window we get after the print pdf get trigger this just an example]

This is my java script code to save the the annotated pdf

Comment: There is no such thing like an upload without user interaction... if that was possible, any script could upload any file from the users computer to the server

Comment: If you have the data within the canvas then you could upload it automatically to the server using AJAX. But I'm not clear if that's actually what the question is, it was a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfect running of your code **there is no problem.**

Purely on your code without aid.

On load of function you open about:blank (I had to switch OFF my pop-up blocker since `window.open('', '_blank');` is not an acceptable way to TAB-NAB in clients devices.)

Then you call the print dialog so it will offer a user to print that blank page , since JavaScript's are not allowed to print under any unwarranted circumstance from remote HTML.

[image]

Perhaps add some libraries to handle the page write task, not run by blank defaults.